# Pinch to Zoom on Text?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to pinch to zoom (or even double tap to zoom) on text in an iOS app? I've made a small app for work, basically a list of emergency contacts, and want to add functionality to make the text bigger by zooming.

I've messed around a little by creating a button to increase the font size programmatically but I'm having trouble passing data back and forward between view controllers.

I think pinch to zoom would be an easier solution if it can be implemented.
Googling I've found examples for zooming images, but nothing about zooming text. I've seen it implemented in safari using what I guess is webkit, but haven't found any coding examples of how it's achieved.

I'd appreciate any input, even if it's just to say it can't be done and at least I can look for another solution.

Comment: Create an NSAttributedString object out of text.  Then turn it into an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This simple code will enlarge or shrink your text that is in the myTextView when pinching. `Swift 3`

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
var pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pinchText(sender:)))
    myTextView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
}

@objc func pinchText(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    var pointSize = myTextView.font?.pointSize
    pointSize = ((sender.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize!;
    myTextView.font = UIFont( name: "arial", size: (pointSize)!)
}
```

*Update* - If you need to preserve the formatted text:

```
@objc func pinchText(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    var pointSize = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "fontSize"))
    pointSize = ((sender.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize!;
    UserDefaults.standard.set(pointSize, forKey: "fontSize")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    let formattedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(attributedString: myTextView!.attributedText)
    formattedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: formattedText.length))
    myTextView.attributedText = formattedText
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply.. this worked treat... thanks!

Comment: wWorked perfectly in a UITextView in Swift 4!  Thank you.

Comment: There are two links for [swift](https://gist.github.com/titopalito/fb9b45718a72f9b12c7abd519438d79a) and [objetive-c](https://gist.github.com/aral/966260). Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for this, @redribben ! Any hint what to do to keep formatted text (i.e. bold/italic)? Following this approach, the formatting gets cleared.

Comment: @redribben - thanks very much. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as expected: I have inline formatted text (e.g. .body text, then bold text, then italic, .headline1 text etc. etc.). When I use your example, the entire text is formatted w/ .body, also the headlines etc. Guess I need to subclass NSTextStorage and create my own parser <sigh>?